# Cannot set new documnt to collection in Firestore

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have tried every different way of setting a new document to Firestore, and just cannot make it happen. I am getting no errors, but the data just never posts. I'm sure I'm missing something easy, but I just cannot figure out what it is

```
import styles from '../../styles/createPost.module.css'
import firebase from '../../firebase/initFirebase'
import { useSession } from 'next-auth/client'

export default function CreatePostButton(props) {
  const [session] = useSession()
 
  const time = Date.now()
  const today = new Date(time)

  const sendData = async() => {
    if (props.postContent) {  
        await firebase.firestore().collection("postData").doc()
        .set({
          postAuthor: session.user.name,
          path: "/cidProfile",
          profileImg: session.user.image,
          postText: props.postText,
          postContent: props.postContent.name,
          postTime: today.toUTCString(),
          reactionsTotal: 1,
          isliked: false,
          commentCount: 0,
          shareCount: 0,
          sharable: props.shareable,
        }).then(alert('Your Post was Sent!'))
    } else {
        await firebase.firestore().collection("postData").doc()
          .set({
            postAuthor: session.user.name,
            path: "/meow",
            profileImg: session.user.image,
            postText: props.postText,
            postTime: today.toUTCString(),
            reactionsTotal: 1,
            isliked: false,
            commentCount: 0,
            shareCount: 0,
            sharable: props.shareable,
          }).then(alert(props.postText))
      } 
  }

  return (
    <div className={styles.postButtonDiv}>
      <button className={styles.postButton} onClick={sendData} disabled={!props.disableButton}>Post</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: "I am getting no errors" Did you consider adding a `catch` to the `set` statements in your code?

Comment: Can you check your console to check if you see any errors in there?

Comment: I had a try/catch that was not working either, this is just the latest form of my trials. I never see any errors in my console, it seems to just refresh the page as if it worked, but then no data is ever added to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try triggering the alert after the promise returned by set is resolved.

```
await firebase.firestore().collection("postData").doc().set({

})
alert("added doc")
```

Also the button type should be "button" or you should prevent default submit action else the page will reload and your code will not execute.

Comment: When I take the alert away from .then and place it immediately after .set, I do not get the alert

Comment: @Justin can you share the latest code  that you have after making the changes? Also I would try `.add()` instead of `.doc().set()` if you want random ID

Comment: const sendData = async() => {
    if (props.postContent) {  
        await firebase.firestore().collection("postData").doc()
        .set({
        })
        alert(props.postContent)
    } else {
        await firebase.firestore().collection("postData").doc()
          .set({
          })
          alert(props.postText)
      } 
  }

Comment: @Justin I would make sure if that function is even running by adding some log statements.

Comment: I have also tried the .add, .doc("name").set with a specified name, and even trying a new collection. I just don't know what is not making it through

Comment: I thought that's what .then(alert()) was doing?

Comment: @Justin I meant before adding to Firestore. Add a log statement right before `if (props.postContent)`.. add `console.log(props.postContent)`

Comment: Yes, I see the console.log. I am also now looking at my network tab and seeing the request cancelled

Comment: @Justin can you share the request and response tab of that request ?

Comment: https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?database=projects%2Fhouse-of-music-c0c01%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&RID=39387&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&%24httpHeaders=X-Goog-Api-Client%3Agl-js%2F%20fire%2F8.8.0%0D%0AContent-Type%3Atext%2Fplain%0D%0AX-Firebase-GMPID%3A1%3A137956244848%3Aweb%3Abdaf19858447d50cf4e3b5%0D%0A&zx=js87lnnvxvfj&t=1

Comment: Request URL: https://firestore.googleapis.com/google.firestore.v1.Firestore/Write/channel?database=projects%2Fhouse-of-music-c0c01%2Fdatabases%2F(default)&VER=8&RID=39387&CVER=22&X-HTTP-Session-Id=gsessionid&%24httpHeaders=X-Goog-Api-Client%3Agl-js%2F%20fire%2F8.8.0%0D%0AContent-Type%3Atext%2Fplain%0D%0AX-Firebase-GMPID%3A1%3A137956244848%3Aweb%3Abdaf19858447d50cf4e3b5%0D%0A&zx=js87lnnvxvfj&t=1
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: count: 1
ofs: 0
req0___data__: {"database":"projects/house-of-music-c0c01/databases/(default)"}

Comment: The response tab just says "Failed to load Response Data"

Comment: I do! Justin悟颺#9472

Answer (score 0):

The syntax appears to be fine, I suspect that this is either a Security Rules problem or a problem with the Firebase Client not being initiated. These errors would naturally be logged or throwing errors in your environment console.

Comment: rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if true;
    }
  }
}
I believe my rules allow for anything goes, the test all post and get from the console. And my get function on the home page is working. Only the .set doesn't